# How to send mail using django

Tags: python, django

So im trying to send a gmail in my django project. But every time i press the submit button i get html 405 error page.

Views:

```py
def send_email(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        name = request.POST.get("name")
        email = request.POST.get("email")
        message = request.POST.get("message")
        send_mail(name, email, message, ["aleksalav123@gmail.com"])
        return HttpResponseRedirect("dashboard/")
```

HTML:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="message_name" placeholder="Full name" id="full_name">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="message_email" placeholder="Email" id="login-email">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="message" placeholder="Poruka" id="text">
    <input type="submit" value="Pošalji" class="login-button">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget to put actual URL to the `action` of the form. Then you send `POST` request to your current URL (which seems to not handle `POST` requests) and you justly receive [`405 Method Not Allowed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405) error.

Comment: Which action do i put? Like action="What in here"

Comment: The URL leading to your `send_email` view.

Comment: Wdym, there is no url that goes to send_email

Comment: After you hit the "Submit" button your browser sends `POST` request to the URL for `action`. So if you want this request to be processed with your view `send_email`, you have to configure URL for your view in `urls.py`.